# How to add a Boolean variable to the struct?

Tags: json, swift

I want to add a `isFavourite` variable to this struct. When I add this the JSON decoding gives an error. How can I manage an external variable in a JSON file?

```
struct ProductModel : Decodable {
    let productData : [ProductData]
    
    private enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case productData = "data"
    }
}

struct ProductData : Identifiable,Decodable,Hashable {
    var id : Int
    var title :String
    var type : String
    var description : String
    var filename : String
    var price : Float
    var rating : Int
    //var imageName : String? = "vegetable"
    
    init() {
        self.id = 0
        self.title = ""
        self.type = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.filename = ""
        self.price = 0.0
        self.rating = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally a good practice is to leave JSON Data Models (aka the ones you receive from API) alone and create separate internal models for your app (from JSON models). There are many reasons, one of them - solving the problem you mentioned. However there are 2 workarounds: 1 - make `isFavourite` optional (this is a hack, not a solution), 2 - have "custom parsing" for this model (i.e. add custom `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`). But I recommend to use different models, like I said

Answer (score 0):

Just add CodingKeys and omit `isFavourite`.

And declare all struct members which will never change as constant (`let`)

```
struct ProductData : Identifiable, Decodable, Hashable {
    let id : Int
    let title :String
    let type : String
    let description : String
    let filename : String

    var price : Float
    var rating : Int

    var isFavourite = false
  
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, type, description, filename, price, rating
    }   
}
```

And if you ever need an initializer write a ***real*** init method with default values. This is more versatile than `init()`.